# MySQL Data directory move (WAMP)

Tags: mysql

I removed the old WAMPServer 2.0 and it left my old MySQL data directory and my.ini intact.
I installed the new WAMPServer 2.2 and need to make my old databases active with the new WAMPServer MySQL.

When I set the data directory in the new my.ini to point to the old data directory, I get this error when trying to start the service:

```
Could not start the wampmysqld service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

No other errors. In the Application Event log I see this:

```
Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

How do I get around this as the old MySQL version was 5.1.36 and the new one is 5.5.16.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to copy over ALL the contents of your old data dir to the new data dir.  Specifically it sounds like you did not copy the mysql folder (read mysql database) over to the new data dir.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for me is binary restore. I move database folders from old WAMP to new WAMP.

eg.
D:\wamp_old\mysql_data\data[db-folder-name]

move to

D:\wamp_new\mysql_data\data[db-folder-name]

Comment: I replaced full wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24 But it's showing databases, not tables

Comment: i am facing the same problem could u help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall all your data by copying over the contents from the old WAMP server to the new one.

Just check your new MySQL version and into wamp/bin/your version/data backup that folder into /backups.

Then copy over wamp/bin/your old version/data to the folder above wamp/bin/your version/data.

This should load WAMP server but with an orange icon.

Go to the backups folder and copy the MySQL, performance schema and test folders into the new.

That should work out.

If you have troubles let me know.

Comment: Why are you shouting ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to copy ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files from old to new data folder. For me it complainted like fallowing in MySQL log.

> InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 50331648 bytes

I copied the above files to the new data folder from the old. It solved my  issue and orange turned to green once I restarted the WAMP server.

Comment: if you didn't copied the old log files, mysql will create the new log files (with innodb_log_file_size) at the startup of server.your case sounds strange to me .